# ctypes.windll.user32.GetKeyState not recognizing key presses

Tags: python, windows, keyboard, ctypes

I have a problem where ctypes.windll.user32.GetKeyState won't detect keys on my keyboard (A, B, C, e.t.c), but it does detect the left and right mouse buttons.

I am trying to make a simple script which detects the lowercase "a" key. I got the number 97 by doing `ord('a')`.

```
import ctypes

def a_pressed():
    return ctypes.windll.user32.GetKeyState(97) > 1

while True:
    if a_pressed():
        print('a is pressed')
```

Am I doing something wrong or is it just some limitation of the API that I don't know about?

Comment: I don't use Windows but maybe `GetKeyState` uses different values then you get from `ord('a')` . `ord()` gives `char code` but system may use different codes to detect key (hardware) On Linux you may get `keycode` which is different then `char code`. System gets keycode and convert to charcode which depends on keyboadr layout (the same key gives different char for English or France layout) BTW: there are Python modules like `keyboard` or `pynput` which can detect pressed keys. Maybe you should check source code to see if they use `GetKeyState`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[MS.Docs]: GetKeyState function (winuser.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeystate) (**emphasis** is mine):

> A virtual key. If the desired virtual key is a letter or digit (**A through Z, a through z**, or 0 through 9), *nVirtKey* must be set to **the ASCII value** of that character. For other keys, it must be a virtual-key code.

is "a bit" misleading.

From *ASCII*'s *PoV*, there's a clear difference between (for example):

- ***a***: 0x61 (97)
- ***A***: 0x41 (65)

From keyboard's *PoV*, things are a bit different (when pressing a key):

- <kbd>a</kbd>: The key on the 3<sup>rd</sup> row and 2<sup>nd</sup> column, at the right of <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> (on *US* keyboards)
- <kbd>A</kbd>: **Same as above**, but with either:

  - <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> on
  - <kbd>Shift</kbd> also pressed

[[MS.Docs]: Virtual-Key Codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes) makes things clear: in order to check the state of <kbd>A</kbd> (or <kbd>a</kbd>), **0x41** (**65**) must be checked (97 corresponds to <kbd>NumPad1</kbd>).

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import time
import ctypes as ct
from ctypes import wintypes as wt


def main(*argv):
    user32 = ct.WinDLL("User32.dll")
    GetKeyState = user32.GetKeyState
    GetKeyState.argtypes = (ct.c_int,)
    GetKeyState.restype = wt.USHORT  # !!! It's actually wt.SHORT, but chose unsigned for display purposes !!!

    while 1:
        vkc = 0x41  # 65, 'A'
        ks = GetKeyState(vkc)
        print("Key (0x{:02X}) state: 0x{:04X}\nPressed: {:d}".format(vkc, ks, ks >> 15))
        time.sleep(0.5)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q069599484]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.08.07_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.8.7 (tags/v3.8.7:6503f05, Dec 21 2020, 17:59:51) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> Key (0x41) state: 0x0000
> Pressed: 0
> Key (0x41) state: 0x0000
> Pressed: 0
> Key (0x41) state: 0x0000
> Pressed: 0
> Key (0x41) state: 0x0000
> Pressed: 0
> Key (0x41) state: 0xFF81
> Pressed: 1
> Key (0x41) state: 0xFF81
> Pressed: 1
> Key (0x41) state: 0xFF81
> Pressed: 1
> Key (0x41) state: 0xFF81
> Pressed: 1
> Key (0x41) state: 0x0001
> Pressed: 0
> ...
> ```

An example of how to use the function:

```py
def is_key_pressed(virtual_key_code):
    return bool(GetKeyState(virtual_key_code) >> 15)


# Examples

is_key_pressed(ord("A"))  # A (a)
is_key_pressed(0x1B)  # Esc
```

Comment: Thanks for the awesome response! But how can I convert from char codes to these kinds?

Comment: What do you mean? I gave an example for *A* (*a*), it's the same for all the other letters / digits. The other keys codes are in the 2nd *URL*.

Comment: Okay, I see now. Thank you!