# Capture all keypresses of the system with Tkinter

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, keyboard, pythoncom

I'm coding a little tool that displays the key presses on the screen with Tkinter, useful for screen recording.

**Is there a way to get a listener for all key presses of the system *globally* with Tkinter?** (for every keystroke including <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, ..., even when the Tkinter window does not have the focus)

I currently know a solution with `pyHook.HookManager()`, `pythoncom.PumpMessages()`, and also solutions from [Listen for a shortcut (like WIN+A) even if the Python script does not have the focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59191177/listen-for-a-shortcut-like-wina-even-if-the-python-script-does-not-have-the-f) but is there a 100% `tkinter` solution?

Indeed, [`pyhook`](https://pypi.org/project/pyHook/) is only for Python 2, and [`pyhook3`](https://github.com/gggfreak2003/PyHook3) seems to be abandoned, so I would prefer a **built-in Python3 / Tkinter solution** for Windows.

Comment: You may are intrested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69606292/13629335). Its a builtin solution for ms windows. While I like the external libary [pywin32](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32api__GetKeyboardState_meth.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution 1**: if you need to catch keyboard events in your current window, you can use:

```
from tkinter import *
 
def key_press(event):
    key = event.char
    print(f"'{key}' is pressed")
 
root = Tk()
root.geometry('640x480')
root.bind('<Key>', key_press)
mainloop()
```

**Solution 2**: if you want to capture keys regardless of which window has focus, you can use [`keyboard`](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard)

Comment: It's not possible without external library.

Comment: Take a look here: https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard

Comment: Note: `keyboard` sadly has some drawbacks compared to other libraries such as `pynput.keybaord`, for me some fast keystrokes were not caught by the former, but they were by the latter.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in [tkinter using two keys at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39606019/tkinter-using-two-keys-at-the-same-time), you can detect all key pressed at the same time with the following:

```py
history = []
def keyup(e):
    print(e.keycode)
    if  e.keycode in history :
        history.pop(history.index(e.keycode))

        var.set(str(history))

def keydown(e):
    if not e.keycode in history :
        history.append(e.keycode)
        var.set(str(history))

root = Tk()
root.bind("<KeyPress>", keydown)
root.bind("<KeyRelease>", keyup)
```

Comment: Thanks but it seems that this only catch keystrokes if the Tkinter window has the focus (I'm looking for a solution for all keystrokes even if the window doesn't have the focus, see my question)

Comment: Ah saw the edit. As mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57285092/monitor-keypress-in-tkinter-without-focus, you can put the app logic in one thread, and the key detection in another or you can use systemhotkey package