# Posting a WM_KEYDOWN message without the following WM_CHAR message for Automating Ctrl+A

Tags: python, winapi, pywin32, pywinauto, win32gui

I'm trying to send a <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> message to a certain application using Python with the `win32api` module.

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> and checking the messages using Spy++, this is the result:

[image]

The `WM_CHAR` message after `WM_KEYDOWN` for `A` has ASCII code 1, which is "Start of heading (SOH)".

When I send the same messages with this code:

```py
win32gui.PostMessage(self.hwnd, win32con.WM_KEYDOWN, 0x11,0x1D0001)#VK_CONTROL
time.sleep(0.1)
win32gui.PostMessage(self.hwnd, win32con.WM_KEYDOWN, 0x41,0x1E0001)"A"
time.sleep(0.1)
win32gui.PostMessage(self.hwnd, win32con.WM_KEYUP, 0x11,0xC01D0001)
time.sleep(0.1)
win32gui.PostMessage(self.hwnd, win32con.WM_KEYUP, 0x41,0xC01E0001)
```

The result looks like this instead:

[image]

So, the `WM_CHAR` message after `WM_KEYDOWN` for `A` has ASCII code 97, unlike when doing it with the keyboard, so the code does not perform a "select all" in the application.

How do I determine the character code of the `WM_CHAR` message after sending `WM_KEYDOWN`?

Comment: [You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513)

Comment: Use [pywinauto](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) with `backend="uia"`.

Comment: On a side note - even if you could get the correct `WM_CHAR` message generated, notice that your code is releasing the keys in the reverse order as the working keyboard example. Try this for yourself. Open Notepad or other text editor, type in some text, hold down `CTRL+A`, and then release `CTRL` first. You will notice the text is selected and then replaced with repeating `a`s until you release the `A` key. That is not what you want.

Comment: Remy Lebeau, good observation, it doesn't matter on the app I'm working on though

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69606292/4788546. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jonathan mentioned in the article, You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage.

You can try to use [pykeyboard](https://pypi.org/project/pykeyboard/#documentation) in python to implement the function of simulating keyboard input.

```
k = PyKeyboard()

k.press_key(k.control_key)

k.tap_key('a')

k.release_key(k.control_key)
```

Comment: I can simulate keyboard input with PostMessage. without any problems I just can't do Ctrl+A, the reason I'm using win32api is the ability to send keyboard and mouse commands while the application is out of focus which doesn't work with pyautogui, pykeyboard etc.

Comment: @oma Why are you avoiding to use the standard solution: [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32)? Why are you hell-bent on doing it one way (that clearly cannot be made into a general solution anyway)?